# Как так произошло, что footer залез в content?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Здравствуйте, делаю интернет магазин на woocommerce, и столкнулся с проблемой, что футер каким то боком оказался внутри блока .content. Прикладываю файлы шаблоны wocommerce

single-product.php:

```html
get_header( 'shop' ); ?>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="header_wrap">
            <div class="header_wrap_container">
                <div class="row paddingbot15"> <!-- Catalog wraper -->
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 hidden-xs nopadding">
                        <div class="catalog">
                            <?php 
                                wp_nav_menu( array(
                                    'container'       => false,
                                    'menu'  => 'Категории',
                                    'menu_class'      => '',
                                ) );
                             ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php get_sidebar('tagcloud'); ?>
                        <?php get_sidebar('feedback'); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 nopaddingright nopaddingmobile">
                        <div class="goods_wrap">
              <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_before_main_content hook.
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
                 * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
              ?>

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                  <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php get_footer( 'shop' ); ?>
```

archive-product.php:

```html
get_header( 'shop' ); ?>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="header_wrap">
            <div class="header_wrap_container">
                <div class="row paddingbot15"> <!-- Catalog wraper -->
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 hidden-xs nopadding">
                        <div class="catalog">
                            <?php 
                                wp_nav_menu( array(
                                    'container'       => false,
                                    'menu'  => 'Категории',
                                    'menu_class'      => '',
                                ) );
                             ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php get_sidebar('tagcloud'); ?>
                        <?php get_sidebar('feedback'); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 nopaddingright nopaddingmobile">
                        <div class="goods_wrap">
              <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_before_main_content hook.
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
                 * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
              ?>

                <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>

                  <h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php
                  /**
                   * woocommerce_archive_description hook.
                   *
                   * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
                   * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
                   */
                  do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
                ?>

                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                  <?php
                    /**
                     * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook.
                     *
                     * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
                     * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
                     */
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
                  ?>

                  <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                    <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                      <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

                  <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

                  <?php
                    /**
                     * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook.
                     *
                     * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
                     */
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
                  ?>

                <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

                  <?php wc_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' ); ?>

              <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php get_footer( 'shop' ); ?>
```

Вот что получилось в итоге: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На вопрос "как произошло" ответ простой - "так написан  кривой код". Но не уверен, что волнует именно этот вопрос. Так почему не задать сразу правильный? Ида советую почитать хотя бы основы ВП (про циклы) прежде чем рисовать эти.. с позволения сказать "шаблоны". И метка `php` тут лишняя.

Answer (score 2):

Количество открывающих `div` больше, чем закрывающих.

Comment: а ведь и не поспоришь, что ответ)

Comment: Если можно тыкните мне в морду то место, где не закрыл div очень прошу, вобще ничего не понимаю.

Comment: Конкретно тут вы все закрыли, но есть еще и футер и хедер

Comment: Да как же он тут все закрыл, когда footer у него внутри header-wrap

Comment: Вобщем оказалось что внутри одного из родных WP экшнов и хуков есть незакрытые дивы, решил в свои шаблончики вставить следующее:
</div> <!-- ЧТО БЛ***Ь хз че за костыль но не трогай его будущий разработчик оно работает -->
и вуаля оно рабооотаааеет

Comment: А это, кстати, частая ситуация с экшенами от WC.

Comment: Сдаётся мне, парни вы какую-то ерунду городите. "одного из"...  Есть реальный косяк? Так на оф форуме заявите.

Comment: @DiceMasters - но не злоупотребляйте костылями - появится привычка.  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Код_с_запашком